# Smoothing vectorized zig-zag polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, vector-graphics

I have vectorized raster data using gdal_polygonize, which produced rough looking polygons like this [image]

I would like to smooth out vertices to produce neat looking polygons. So far I have had a moderate progress with a combination of ST_SIMPLIFY and ST_CHAIKINSMOOTHING, but resuls could be better. The best approach could be to convert jagged vertices to straight diagonal lines and apply chaikin smoothing after that. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: If you can find the jagged corners, you can take those two linestrings and build a square, with that square you can compute the diagonal https://postgis.net/docs/ST_BoundingDiagonal.html

Comment: You can turn your polygons into linestrings and then explode them into individual segments https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174472/in-postgis-how-to-split-linestrings-into-their-individual-segments